# Content page unload event

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, master-pages

I have a content page and on that there are two button - DoTransactionButton and CancelTranButton 
 I have a session state ["TransactionDone"] ( True of False).
I set ["TransactionDone"]= false on - Page not post back.
and I set this as True when DoTransaction button is clicked.

Now i want to capture this information while leaving on the same page and call some function if DoTransaction is not clicked. 
Please let me know if i need to capture some event of content page where i can call this function.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with OnUnload event on content page by overriding but Page_Load is called first and OnUnload is called after that. The moment page is loading for the first time.